# Как запустить команду в cmd

Tags: c++, windows

Как можно запустить команду `cmd` через `system("");` что бы при этом не открывалась консоль именно при вызове `system("");`

Comment: Оно откроется в любом случае, если использовать `system`. Даже `"start /B mybat.bat"` при выполнении через `system` всё равно откроет окно, и сразу же его закроет.

Comment: Кросс-платформенная альтернатива ответу ниже: https://gitlab.com/eidheim/tiny-process-library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const wchar_t* x = L"/C ipconfig > 1.log";
ShellExecute(0, L"open", L"cmd.exe", x, 0, SW_HIDE);
```